# Image can't upgrade in CI PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I using CI for build my website and i have some issue with my code, my profile page can't change image for profile. This is my code

- Controller

  ```
  public function edit()
  {
    $data['title'] = 'Edit Profile';
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Full Name', 'required|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
      $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
      $this->load->view('user/edit', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
      $name = $this->input->post('name');
      $email = $this->input->post('email');

      // cek jika gambar yang akan diubah

      $upload_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];


      if ($upload_image) {
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']      = '2048';
        $config['upload_path']   = './assets/img/profile/';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
          $new_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');
          $this->db->set('image', $new_image);
        } else {
          echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
      }


      $this->db->set('name', $name);
      $this->db->where('email', $email);
      $this->db->update('user');

      $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your profile has been updated</div>');
      redirect('user');
  ```
- View

  ```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Picture</div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <img src="<?= base_url('assets/img/profile/') . $user['image']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" name="image">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="image">Choose file</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  ```

What should I do to solved this issue?

Comment: Can you provide more context? What happens exactly? Are there any errors? Did you check log files?

Comment: nothing errors that was i saw, but my profile photo not upgraded when i try to change this image,

Comment: Did you step through the code with a debugger yet? Or added log message or var_dumps in the code to see what gets executed?

Comment: I've added var_dump in the code and show normal like tutorial that was i saw, but data in database and folder upload image not change

Comment: So this hints at `$new_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');` not getting executed. If you strategically placed var_dumps across the code, what code path does get executed?

Comment: why this code not getting executed?

Comment: i try to placed $upload_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      var_dump($upload_image);
      die;

Comment: it's show string of name

Comment: I don't know why it's not getting executed. Actually, I doubt anyone will be able to tell you without using a debugger. Like I said: you will need to figure out which code path gets executed to narrow it down.